# Can I pass the minus (-) or plus (+) sign as params into a method and use them in the method?

Tags: ruby

I have a class, that has an attribute that's an integer. When I calculate the sum/difference of two instances of that class I actually want to calculate the sum/difference of their attribute. So my class looks like this:

```
class A

attr_reader :a

def initialize(a)
@a = a
end

def +(instance_of_a)
  A.new(self.a + instance_of_a.a)
end

def -(instance_of_a)
  A.new(self.a - instance_of_a.a)
end

end
```

Is there a way I could write a method to take the logic out of those 2 (- and +) methods and store them into the new method? I would like to write something like this:

```
def operation(sign, instance_of_a)
A.new(self.a sign instance_of_a.a)
end

def +(instance_of_a)
operation(+, instance_of_a)
end

def -(instance_of_a)
operation(-, instance_of_a)
end
```

Obviously this doesn't work like this, but I can't figure a way to implement something like this. That's probably because I don't really understand what the `+` and `-` are. I can't do something like `-.class.name` and I can't do something like this either:

```
def -
10 __method__ 5
end
```

Any clarification on this matter is more than welcome, thanks.

Comment: `A.new(5).public_send(:+, A.new(42))`

Comment: Also, I would expect (as a vast majority of devs all around) that `def +(instance_of_a)` would return `A.new(self.a + instance_of_a.a)` not a raw `Integer`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks a lot. About the second comment, you're right, it is written like that in the original code, tried to simplify this version and ended up with this. I'll edit it

Comment: Also fancy trick with unary operators: `42.public_send(:-@) #⇒ -42`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. When your are calling a method on a object, your are sending a message to the object. In ruby *send* using you can send messages(call that method) to that object. For example to 1.+2 would give me three.

Now You could implement your operation method like

```
     def operation(operation,instance_of_a)
         a.send(operation,instance_of_a.a)
     end
```

Your + method would be

```
             operation("+",instance_of_a)
```

Comment: BTW, `1.(+2)` would never give you `3` back.

Comment: Also, `2.+@.+2.-@` is perfectly legit ruby-way to write zero.

Comment: Ruby uses `@` suffix to distinguish unary operations. When one wants to reimplement say prefix tilde `~5`, the operator to declare should be `def ~@; ... ..`. So the above is just `+2 + -2`. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-2D-40